# django messages framework not adding messages in RedirectView

Tags: django

I have the following redirect view code for a payment gateway web callback

```
  class Callback(RedirectView):

      def get_redirect_url(self, transaction_goid):
          try:
              # do some work
          except Exception as e:
              messages.error(self.request, str(e))
              print dir(messages.get_messages(self.request))
              print messages.get_messages(self.request)._loaded_messages
              return reverse('home')
```

The problem is messages are not adding to the messages storage, _loaded_messages always give empty list `[]` and on home page not displaying any messages

I have double checked `settings` with documentation and ensure it is configured properly.

My gut feeling is that since it's a redirect and it's not going through the middlewares properly

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not within messages framework, the actual problem is `str(e)` was returning an empty string and messages do not add empty strings.